# Sum of the Digits program error

Tags: java, sum-of-digits

I have been working on a program to take integer x and find any numbers whose sum of the digits multiplied by x equals the number. my code has worked for numbers 2, 3, and 4, but beyond that is returns various errors regardless of what i am doing. any help would be greatly appreciated.

my code:

```
package SumOfTheDigits;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
         int a = 3;
         int x = 1;
         int solutions =  (9 - ((((10 * x) - (a * x))/(a - 1)) % 9))/(((10 * x) - 
                          (a * x))/(a - 1));

         for(int z = 1; z < solutions + 2; z++)
         {
             if((z * 10) + ((10 * z) - (a * z))/(a - 1) == a * (z + ((10 * z) - 
                   (a * z))/(a - 1)))
             {
                 System.out.println(z + "" + ((10 * z) - (a * z))/(a - 1));
             }      
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does 'various errors' mean?

Comment: Yep, "various errors" could mean that it sets your toaster on fire. Please do tell the important details.

Comment: i forgot to mention that the input goes to variable "a", and it is supposed to be ten or less. also it gave a divide by zero error and at one point did not run the system.out.println command.

Comment: Any time you've got that many parens you've got a problem with your design.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `/ by zero` exceptions because your numbers are stored as integers, that means when you would normally get a decimal value < 1 you actually get 0. Take this example from your code

```
int a = 15;
int x = 1;
// with the bottom half of your equation
int solutions = ....other math.../(((10 * x) - (a * x))/(a - 1))

// (((10 * 1) - (15 * 1))/(15 - 1)) = (-5/14) - > converted to integer = 0
```

So..

```
int solutions = ....other math.../0
```

and an error is thrown. What you should do is convert all your `int` to doubles to allow the equation to be evaluated correctly.

```
double a = 10;
double x = 1;
double solutions = ....;
```

Also have some faith in order of operations and remove some parentheses :), theres so many it is a headache to look at

```
double temp = (10*x - a*x)/(a - 1);
double solutions = (9 - (temp % 9))/temp;
```

Comment: do you have any idea how i could expand this to work with a value of x for any number of digits?

Comment: @AlexanderGulea I couldn't tell you because I have no idea what you are even trying to do with this program :). Just think about it for a bit, throw your best shot at it and keep working at it. Im sure you will find a way to make it happen if you really give it a good try.

Comment: i wanted to get the program to return values when the input is ten or greater. so far input that is greater then 10 the program returns nothing or it returns a strange decimal value.